# Internet connection problem with Ubuntu 22 - SOLVED

Tags: networking, internet

I have a dual book Surface pro 7 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22 installed.
I can get out on Internet with Windows and also with my sgin  Android pad. But not with my Ubuntu 22. With Ubuntu I get a question mark on my internet icon. It does not help me to deactivate the question mark.
What info should I share so you may get a clue on what is going on with Internet?

SOLUTION

That will not help the Ubuntu team. But I got internet again installing Linux Mint.
Now I am back in the Linux world I prefer over Windows.
I wonder however why Ubuntu did not allow me to connect to Internet. Question mark continuously....

Comment: Installing mint not a helpful "solution" and doesn't help pinpoint the original issue. I don't think the details you have provided would be enough to solve your Ubuntu connection issues